TesseractNot Found Error is displayed after deploying app on render even after trying several methods
I am trying to deploy app through render but after executing there is error as
TesseratNotFound or Tesseract is not installed
Even though I have added package.txt , requirements.txt as well as build.sh how to solve this error
Suggestions to resolve the error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr? Do you have the path set correctly?
